# Why can't I use the -> operator for a struct pointer in main?

Tags: pointers, dot-operator

I thought that the general rule of thumb was that the -> operator was used for accessing members of struct pointers, and the . operator was used for accessing members of an actual struct. In my code, I thought I created a struct pointer, but I ended up still having to use the . operator. Can someone explain why?

```
typedef struct Robot
{
    char **brain;
    int size;
} Robot;

int main(void)
{
    char buffer[100];
    Robot *dalek = malloc(sizeof(Robot)*2);

    for(i = 0; i < 2; i++)
        dalek[i].brain = malloc(sizeof(char*) * 3);

    for(i = 0; i < 3; i++)
    {
        scanf("%s", buffer);
        dalek[0].brain[i] = malloc(sizeof(char) * strlen(buffer));
        strcpy(dalek[0].brain[i], buffer);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

`dalek` is a pointer, and `dalek[i]` is equivalent to `*(dalek + i)`, i.e. it dereferences. If you want to use the arrow, say `(dalek + i)->brain` etc.

Answer (score 0):

`dalek[i]` is defined as `*(dalek+i)`. So when you do `dalek[i]->brain` you are really doing `*(*(dalek+i)).brain`, dereferencing a single pointer twice. If you really want to use the `->` operator, you could use `(dalek+i)->brain`.